# Android 4.3 LE Bluetooth client server conflict

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I am using Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 4.3
I am trying to convert an app that ran on Samsung's LEB API with Android 4.2.2.
I can discover and connect (`connectGatt`) to the peripheral and run all "client" code successfully, provided I do not try to connect as a server.

Whenever I connected

```
mBluetoothGattServer = mBluetoothManager.openGattServer(this, mGattServerCallbacks);
```

the LogCat's indicated that the communication with BluetoothGatt cease.

I've tried to `openGattServer` after all the Gatt services are discovered. I attempt to `addServices` in the `GattServerCallback` `onConnectionStateChange`. The code runs but I do not get an onServiceAdded callback

Both the "gatt client" and "gatt server" code in my app fails to run.

I do get `onConnectionStateChange` callbacks for both.

How, when and where (`MainActivity` or `BLEService`) do I instantiate `mBluetoothGattServer`?

Is this documented somewhere? With some sample code?

The first part of my question is resolved temporarily. I started a new thread, added a one second delay, then called openGattServer. My "client" code now works fine. (I am not happy with this - it was a try generated out of frustration - I may try using a queue if I can get server code to work).

I do get a `GattServerCallback` for `onConnectionStateChange`.

However, I do not seem to have yet got any "server" code running.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a temporary solution.
When I instantiated the mBluetoothGattServer object, the callback "onConnectionStateChange" was called while mBluetoothGattServer = null (still). This was a surprise as instantiating the object caused the callback to be registered. I put a delay into the code of onConnectionStateChange until mBluetoothGattServer != null (with suitable limit on number of tries) and was able to add a service successfully. At the time of writing it appears that I will have to add services one at a time and wait for the onServiceAdded callback before adding each service (this is not yet tested)

I must say the Samsung BLE SDK was easier to understand and manage.

Comment: Any updates? I'm getting this same problem developing with a Nexus 9 and it's been over a year

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the `BluetoothGattServer` before calling `connectGatt` on any `BluetoothDevice` :

```
mBluetoothGattServer = mBluetoothManager.openGattServer(self, mGattServerCallbacks);
mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallbacks);
```

The fact is you only need one `BluetoothGattServer` instance, and the callbacks in `mGattServerCallbacks` will be called simultaneously with those in `mGattCallbacks`.

When you connect a device, the methods called `onConnectionStateChange` will be called in both callbacks wrappers.